# banner message before login prompt

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I need to display a banner message before login by SSH.

I have tried changing the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the parameter Banner.
Banner `/etc/ssh/sshd-banner`

After these changes, I get the banner message but it is after I provide the user name.

But my intention is to get the banner message before "login as" prompt.

I would prefer to have banner followed by login as prompt.

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart the ssh server, with something like:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

... after that, you will get the message before you input the password, but after the login. This may vary depending on which SSH client you are using for the connection.

Comment: sshd is in rpm based flavors for ubuntu its only ssh ie `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if there is a posibility to get the banner message before the login ?